# Fed MED/EE, Fed OASDI/EE and CA OASDI/EE visa status F1 - OPT

Tags: united-states, taxes, social-security, f1-student-visa

When I worked as intern on CPT, my employer deducted the following taxes from my pay check:

- Fed MED/EE
- Fed OASDI/EE
- CA OASDI/EE

My tax agent said I need to request them to get that back or fill a form along with my taxes. I did and got 100% of it back. Tax agent said that you should deal with it during your first pay check and they will not deduct it from there on.

Now, I am working on OPT full-time with my visa status as F1. My new employer is also deducting same taxes for me. I contacted payroll department but they sent me a mail stating "Those are default taxes and we cannot stop that."

How do I let them know that I am exempt from those taxes?

Comment: For Federal tell them to look at page 42 of publication 15 or [the web version just above this link](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p15#en_US_2019_publink100020655). However if their system isn't set up to handle this, and you can't switch to a different employer (as a citizen or permanent resident could), you may be out of luck.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the info. I contacted my company's payroll (twice) and explained my status. They investigated and found that my HR did not update my current situation during hiring process and they had no idea on my status, so by default they deducted my taxes. Requested HR to change status, my deductions from previous paychecks will be deposited in next one.